# If statement based on created by profile name to show value is custom formula field

Tags: formula-field, custom-field, profile, user, opportunity-lineitem

This new field will be called "Line item Total Test" on Opportunity Product.

**This Formula is not working-**

```
IF(CreatedBy.Profile.Name = "Standard User", TotalPrice),
IF(CreatedBy.Profile.Name = "Administrative User", Grand_Total__c),
'0' 
)
)
```

**Our Goal** is if the opportunity or product is created by someone who belongs to the "Standard User" profile than the number in the Total Price field (standard field on opportunity product) will show. If the opportunity or product is created by someone who belongs to the "Administrative User" profile than the number in the Grand_Total__C field (custom formula on opportunity product) will show

Comment: this is your 3rd formula field question,  unless I am mistaken, you seem to have frequent syntax errors, have you considered learning the basics? Trailheads perhaps, and further more reading the documentation? [An Introduction to Formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas)

Comment: I'm learning as I go. I'll read the info on the link you provided to further my limited knowledge.

Comment: Should I not post on here anymore? I did post three questions but two posts were the same (I just didn't know how to ask it correctly) I mean will anyone help me write this/ explain it?

Comment: I am simply recommending you  learn the basics and understand what you are doing rather than post a quesiton here everytime something "doesnt work" This forum is not intended to teach you the basics nor is it a free coding service. We are here to help you with specific problems you are facing after having demonstrated an effort in trying to resolve this by your own. If you tried, and read the documentation, feel free to link it and highlight the part you dont understand alongside what you are attempting.

Comment: @jlh123 You're welcome to post, and I'll be happy to write up an answer in an hour or so if no one else gets to it first. There's just some level of expectation that you put in some work and research to get started and frame your question, and this is basic formula syntax. How about we answer and also include some resources to help you go further with it?

Comment: Wow. I've been using Salesforce for 6 months so I am very new to this. I've had trouble with two formulas. I admit I'm learning. I'm not using this as a free service. I'm trying to learn. I didn't realize this was only for specific questions or for people that can provide you a satisfactory level of proof. If anyone would have asked what else I tried I've tried several other formulas I tried that were equally (maybe even more) wrong (after work, in a sandbox, just trying to learn). I don't feel either of us are benefiting from this conversation. Have a good night. this was at @glls

Comment: There is nothing wrong with trying to learn, however, note that there are resources that are specifically tailored to do so such as [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/), there is also a [help poratl](https://help.salesforce.com/home) portal where you can actually "search" for salesforce related resources,. I am not trying to discourage you from using this site, and I do hope you find the above links i posted useful,  I am merely pointing out that there are other resources for you to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

Formulas can be highly counterintuitive if you don't have a background in some kind of code-based discipline.

Here's a couple of key concepts that are in play here.

A **function** in a formula always looks like this:

```
FUNCTION_NAME(list, of, parameters)
```

The parameters can be *literals* (values you write out, like `2.0`), merge fields, expressions like `Amount * 0.5`, or other functions to evaluate. They're always separated by commas.

Different functions require specific sets of parameters.  `IF()` takes 3: a comparison, a value to use when it's true, and a value to use when it's false.

Functions within functions always nest cleanly with matched parentheses:

```
FUNCTION_ONE(2.0, Id, FUNCTION_TWO(ParentId)
```

meaning that the outermost function closes last, and fully encloses all of its parameters in its parentheses. Inner function expressions must nest similarly, always with a balanced set of parentheses around the parameters for a single function.

Here, what you need to do is nest your `IF()` statements so that when the outer one's first parameter is false, its value (the third parameter) is the result of another `IF()` function - which must itself have 3 parameters (condition, when true value, when false value).

That should be enough to express your objective. See if you can stitch the values you're working with into that structure, and make use of the formula editor's Check Syntax button. It will tell you when something's wrong at the code level, as opposed to the behavior level.

### Resources

- [Use Formula Fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/formula_fields) on Trailhead is a good overall intro to formulas.
- There's a nice example of a nested `IF()` in the [Formula Reference](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) under `IF()`.

Comment: Thank you, David. I checked out the materials you suggested and was able to write it. For anyone with less experience reading this here is what worked for me- IF( Opportunity.RecordTypeId = "012390000005zTL", TotalPrice, 
IF(Opportunity.RecordTypeId = "01239000000Uaso", Grand_Total__c, null))

Comment: I am very glad this helped! I hope you feel more confident tackling complex formulas - please don't hesitate to continue asking formula questions. See if you can get to the valid syntax point and you'll have an easier time working through any behavior challenges that arise.